# Обход блокировки по ip при парсинге

Tags: python, парсер, ip

Как обойти блокировку сайта по ip при парсинге на python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Способ 1

Самый правильный способ при проектировании системы парсинга -- это сделать подсистему, которая отвечает за прокси-сервера. Это может быть микросервис или компонент (класс, например) в Вашем приложении.

В себе он может сочетать ранжирование проксей по степени устойчивости или агрегировать любой другой рейтинг, скрывая эту кухню от всех остальных систем.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На картинке Выше Вы можете видеть пример организации модулей. Я преднамеренно не стал связывать прокси-сервис с интернетом, поскольку часто список проксей хардкодится. Но в более продвинутых системах, они регулярно пополняются и валидируются.

## Способ 2

Ещё один способом является использование виртуальных машин из yandex.cloud или google.cloud. Вы можете запускать их с помощью АПИ этих платформ когда Вам нужно, а затем гасить. При этом, здесь потребуются некоторые хитрости в плане автоматизации развёртывания и масштабирования. Но при качественной подготовке, Вы выиграете в цене.

Answer (score 1):

Нет не единственный. Можно использовать VPN. Погуглите на этy тему. Впрочем эффект и принцип работы будет примерно таким же как прокси ;) Спасибо @Вадим Александру за этот коммент.

Answer (score 0):

Единственный выход — использовать прокси сервера. В интернете можете найти много бесплатных прокси

Comment: Парсил прокси с сайта hidemy.name и использовал в методе requests.get(proxies=), но в основном эти попытки тщетны(хотя кол-во прокси около 6000)

Comment: Нет не единственный. Можно использовать VPN. Погуглите на эту тему.

Comment: @VictorVosMottor Ахах, В чем по вашему разница между впн и прокси? Советую вам погуглить на эту тему

Comment: https://www.cactusvpn.com/ru/beginners-guide-to-vpn/difference-between-vpn-and-proxy/

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1223827/are-there-differences-between-a-vpn-and-proxy-server-in-terms-of-anonymity

Comment: Как видете разница есть ;)

Comment: До редактирования не могу

Comment: @VictorVosMottor в контексте обхода блокировки по ip разница не принципиальна

Comment: @andreymal тем не менее это разные вещи ;)

Comment: @VictorVosMottor вы же написали "Нет не единственный. Можно использовать VPN. " а сейчас соглашаетесь с тем, что в контексте этого вопроса разница не принципиальна, как вас понимать?

Comment: Очень просто. VPN != прокси. Так? Вы говорите можно только прокси. А я говорю: "можно VPN, не только прокси". Даже несмотря на одинаковый эффект...

Comment: @VictorVosMottor по факту, вы просто перефразировали мой ответ?

Comment: Я сказал одно, вы — другое. Все равно что `list(map(lambda el: el*2, lst))` даст тоже самое, что и `[i*2 for i in lst]` в питоне, но это разные ответы.

Comment: @VictorVosMottor вы понимаете что впн как раз использует прокси? если через прокси у автора не получилось, каким боком должно получиться через впн? Вы просто отвечаете ради ответа либо обсудить мой ответ? Хотите помоч автору - давайте нормальные советы, а не посылайте его гуглить технологию которая в конечном итоге все равно использует прокси

Comment: Можно сделать это с прокси, можно с vpn. По сути будет одно и то же. У тебя ответ — прокси, у меня vpn, что не так блин?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112779/discussion-between---and-victor-vosmottor).

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1175296/revisions